# Average pooling with Theano

Tags: neural-network, pooling, theano

I am trying to implement another pooling function for neural network with Theano, expect of already existing maxpool, for example average pool.

Using to [this source](https://github.com/quaizarv/deeplearning-benchmark/blob/master/common/theanoWrappers.py), where average pooling is already implemented, my code looks like:

Random initialization just to test:

```
invals = numpy.random.RandomState(1).rand(3,2,5,5)
```

Definition of Theano scalars and functions:

```
pdim = T.scalar('pool dim', dtype='float32')
pool_inp = T.tensor4('pool input', dtype='float32')
pool_sum = TSN.images2neibs(pool_inp, (pdim, pdim))
pool_out = pool_sum.mean(axis=-1) 
pool_fun = theano.function([pool_inp, pdim], pool_out, name = 'pool_fun', allow_input_downcast=True)
```

TSN is [theano.sandbox.neighbours](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/sandbox/neighbours.html)

And the call of the function:

```
pool_dim = 2
temp = pool_fun(invals, pool_dim)
temp.shape = (invals.shape[0], invals.shape[1], invals.shape[2]/pool_dim,
            invals.shape[3]/pool_dim)
print ('invals[1,0,:,:]=\n', invals[1,0,:,:])
print ('output[1,0,:,:]=\n',temp[1,0,:,:])
```

And I am getting an error:

```
TypeError: neib_shape[0]=2, neib_step[0]=2 and ten4.shape[2]=5 not consistent
Apply node that caused the error: Images2Neibs{valid}(pool input, MakeVector.0, MakeVector.0)
Inputs shapes: [(3, 2, 5, 5), (2,), (2,)]
Inputs strides: [(200, 100, 20, 4), (4,), (4,)]
Inputs types: [TensorType(float32, 4D), TensorType(float32, vector), TensorType(float32, vector)]
Use the Theano flag 'exception_verbosity=high' for a debugprint of this apply node.
```

I don't really understand this error. Would be glad to have any suggestions how to correct this error or example of other pooling techniques, programmed in Theano.

Thanks!

Edit: with the ignoring the border, it works perfectly

```
pool_sum = TSN.images2neibs(pool_inp, (pdim, pdim), mode='ignore_borders')

invals[1,0,:,:]=
[[ 0.01936696  0.67883553  0.21162812  0.26554666  0.49157316]
[ 0.05336255  0.57411761  0.14672857  0.58930554  0.69975836]
[ 0.10233443  0.41405599  0.69440016  0.41417927  0.04995346]
[ 0.53589641  0.66379465  0.51488911  0.94459476  0.58655504]
[ 0.90340192  0.1374747   0.13927635  0.80739129  0.39767684]]
output[1,0,:,:]=
[[ 0.33142066  0.30330223]
[ 0.42902038  0.64201581]]
```

Answer (score 1):

`invals` has shape `(5, 5)` in the last two dimensions, however you want to pool over `(2, 2)` subsets. This only works if you ignore the border (i.e. the last column and the last row of `invals`).

Comment: Or enlarge an input array with median values:

poolsize = (2,2)
if invals.shape[2] % pool_dim != 0:
    print("Rows")
    rest = invals.shape[2] % poolsize[0]
    print(rest)
    #shape of ival
    invals = numpy.lib.pad(invals, ((0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0), (0, rest)), 'median')
    
if invals.shape[3] % pool_dim != 0:
    print("Columns")
    rest = invals.shape[3] % poolsize[1]
    print(rest)
    invals = numpy.lib.pad(invals, ((0, 0), (0, 0), (rest, 0), (0, 0)), 'median')